# If string contains a word then do not send the discord embed

Tags: python, discord.py

I want it so if the var StoreNames4 contains the word "Closed" then it will not send the embed and move on to the next part of the script. I am not sure how to do that I have tried multiple ways but it still seems to send every time.

```
# Discord Embed Setup 4 
            embed = Embed(
                description="A new "+ItemTitles+" is available!",
                color=0x0d0d22,
                timestamp='now'  # sets the timestamp to current time
                )

            embed.set_title(title="**"+ItemTitles+"**")
            embed.add_field(name="**Release:**", value=Dates, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="**ColorWay:**", value=ColorWays, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="**Retail:**", value=Retails, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="**PID:**", value=PIDs, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="**Store Name:**", value=StoreNames4, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="**Close Date:**", value=CloseDates4, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="**Type:**", value=Types4, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="**Country:**", value=Countries4, inline=True)


            embed.set_footer(text='TEST', icon_url='ICONURL')

            embed.set_image(image.get_attribute('src'))

            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

            print("Embed sent to discord!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `StoreNames4` is not "closed" using `if StoreNames4 != "Closed": ...`, putting your embed code within that if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to send embed if `StoreNames4` variable is 'Closed', you can do this:

```
if 'Closed' not in StoreNames4:
    embed = Embed(
                description="A new "+ItemTitles+" is available!",
                color=0x0d0d22,
                timestamp='now'  # sets the timestamp to current time
                )

    embed.set_title(title="**"+ItemTitles+"**")
    embed.add_field(name="**Release:**", value=Dates, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**ColorWay:**", value=ColorWays, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**Retail:**", value=Retails, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**PID:**", value=PIDs, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**Store Name:**", value=StoreNames4, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**Close Date:**", value=CloseDates4, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**Type:**", value=Types4, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**Country:**", value=Countries4, inline=True)

    embed.set_footer(text='TEST', icon_url='ICONURL')

    embed.set_image(image.get_attribute('src'))

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    print("Embed sent to discord!")
```

Comment: Sorry I should of clarified, I am looking for a word in the var StoreNames4. It will print like this "Store Name, Closed"

Comment: So you want to send the embed but if store is closed, storenames4 variable must equal to "Store Name, Closed", am I right?

Comment: It has a different store name every time thats why I am just looking for the word "Closed", but if the variable contains the word closed then I do not want to send the embed.

Comment: I'm confused... You have a variable named `StoreNames4`. It has everytime a diffirent value like 'Test', 'Try'. But if the store is closed, then the value is 'Test, Closed', 'Try, Closed'. Is it like that?

Comment: Its scraping data from a website. So the string in StoreNames4 will be different every time.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correct you want the embed to be sent if only the variable `StoreNames4` doesn't have the word `Closed` in it. If so you can use this if-statement to check if 'closed' is not in `StoreNames4`: `if "Closed" not in StoreNames4`

---

#### Full code

```py
if "Closed" not in StoreNames4:
    embed = Embed(
        description="A new "+ItemTitles+" is available!",
        color=0x0d0d22,
        timestamp='now'  # sets the timestamp to current time
        )

    embed.set_title(title="**"+ItemTitles+"**")
    embed.add_field(name="**Release:**", value=Dates, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**ColorWay:**", value=ColorWays, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**Retail:**", value=Retails, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**PID:**", value=PIDs, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**Store Name:**", value=StoreNames4, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**Close Date:**", value=CloseDates4, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**Type:**", value=Types4, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**Country:**", value=Countries4, inline=True)


    embed.set_footer(text='TEST', icon_url='ICONURL')

    embed.set_image(image.get_attribute('src'))

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    print("Embed sent to discord!")
```

This is assuming `StoreNames4` is assigned to a string